# TCPDF, avoid page break within a set of rows of a table

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF with a long table containing for each category, product a row.

A `nobr=\"true\"` tag is within each tr to avoid a page brake but sometimes, I have the category at the end of a page and the products on the next (without the category above in this case).

Is it any possible to group each category with their products to avoid a page break within a category?

```
<table width="1100px">
<tr nobr="true"><td colspan="3">Category</td></tr>
<tr nobr="true"><td>Product 1</td><td>Price</td><td>Info</td></tr>
<tr nobr="true"><td>Product 2</td><td>Price</td><td>Info</td></tr>
<tr nobr="true"><td colspan="3">Category</td></tr>
<tr nobr="true"><td>Product 1</td><td>Price</td><td>Info</td></tr>
</table>
```

The only solution I found was to close and open the table for each category but there must be a more cleaner way to do this, right?

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: it's just a table, not much to share.

Comment: Good luck with that!